# DocuSign Service Integration Authentication using Organization Admin to grant consent on the app and impersonate everyone

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

I have been successfully using Service Integration Authentication to create an envelope. Here are the steps I have made to authenticate the user.

1. Granting consent individually for Organization Admin A by redirecting them to this URL:

   `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
   response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=7c2b8d7e-83c3-4940-af5e-cda8a50dd73f&redirect_uri=https://client.example.com/callback`

   After Organization Admin A clicked "Accept" the consent is granted
2. Create the JWT using code provided in the SDK, here's the information I have provided in the JWT:

   `{
     "iss": {integrator key},
     "sub": <user ID of Organization Admin A>,
     "iat": <timestamp when issued>,
     "exp": <expiration date>,
     "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
     "scope": "signature impersonation"
   }`
3. Using this generated Jwt I made a `POST` request to `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion={JWT}` to exchange for an Access Token
4. Use that generated access token I have successfully created an envelope

So at this stage I have confirmed that I have generated the JWT correctly, created Integrator Key correctly, I have also provided the right information in the create JWT request.

Then I realized from my application it would be ideal if I don't have to do step 1 above all the time. I would like to grant consent without the UI (redirect URL) and be able to impersonate everyone in the organization. So here's what I did:

1. Created another organization admin: Organization Admin B. Since Admin A has already granted his consent hence no longer suitable for my test. Both of these users are Organization Admin with Permission Set "Organization".
2. I then went to Application and clicked "Authorize Application" and linked it to the correct Integrator Key, permission: "signature impersonation"
3. From here I created the JWT, the only information changed in the payload now is the userId pointing to Organization Admin B:

   `{
     "iss": {integrator key},
     "sub": <user ID of Organization Admin B>,
     "iat": <timestamp when issued>,
     "exp": <expiration date>,
     "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
     "scope": "signature impersonation"
   }`
4. JWT generated I went ahead to make a `POST` request to `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion={JWT}` to exchange for an Access Token and here's what I got:

   `{
     "error": "consent_required"
   }`

If I have already "Authorize Application", how could consent be required?

I have also tried omitting the userId in the JWT request because according to this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-developers-look-inside-new-authentication-apis/)

> The user id of the principal you are requesting a token for. If
>   omitted a token will be issued to represent the application itself
>   instead of a user in the system.

and that essentially what I want. But when I got the JWT generated and successfully generated an Access Token like below:

`{
   "access_token":"",
   "token_type":"Application",
   "expires_in":28800
}`

Notice the `token_type` is now "Application" not "Bearer"
, I will then get "either username or password" is not corrected when I tried to create an envelope with that Access Token.

`{
   "errorCode":"USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
   "message":"One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"
}`

This is so confusing as there isn't an article showing step by step on how to use the Organization Admin Tool to grant consent on the app and impersonate everyone. Most of the articles only address individual granting consent. Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, you can only grant Org Authorization to an integrator key owned by your Organization, and that consent only applies to users that are within a claimed domain.

So, if your Organization has claimed example.com, you can grant consent for user@example.com, but not for user@gmail.com.

To grant Organization consent, navigate to the Org Admin dashboard > Applications > Authorize Applications. From the 'Select an Application' dropdown, you'll see all integrator keys that are associated with accounts within your Organization. From there, you can grant org-wide consent.

Comment: Yes, I have already Authorized Applications associated with integrator key within my Organization" as mentioned above. The integrator key was created using my account within the organization so that should be fine. The only thing that I haven't done is claiming domain, I wonder if this is why I kept having "consent_required" error. Why do I have to claim domain if I'm not using SSO and this is just a demo account for testing purpose? Any chance I can bypass this?

Comment: No, you will not be able to bypass this and continue using org consent. Organization Consent only applies to members with accounts that are within your claimed domain.
The only bypass would be to grant individual consent instead of org.